# mostrar datos de un array en un modal segun el boton seleccionado

Tags: javascript, html5, vue.js, modal

Tengo un codigo que esta en VUEJS que almacena datos como (nombre, direccion, telefono y mapa) en un array, pero que en el html solo muestro el nombre , direccion y telefono por lo tanto quiero mostrar el dato (mapa) en un modal al presionar el boton ver mapa de cada elemento y devolver el valor de mapa segun el item o boton presionado. 
Gracias agradecere cualquier sugerencia o ayuda que se brinde.

//de momento en la propiedad methods: llamo al index y segun el boton que se presione cambia el estado  a true y cambia las clases: estaba probando de esa manera.

```js
class clasSede{
    constructor(nombre,direccion,telefono){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }
}


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        search:'',
        sedesCorreos:[
            {nombre:"SAN ISIDRO", direccion:"Av. Jorge Basadre 265 - San Isidro", telefono:"01-5439963",mapa:"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3902.7528105136344!2d-77.07477358472353!3d-11.99159864414279!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x9105ce5be8ba21fb%3A0x292919764ae454a5!2sAv.+Carlos+Izaguirre+931%2C+Los+Olivos+15301!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2spe!4v1561161587300!5m2!1ses-419!2spe"},
            {nombre:"MIRAFLORES", direccion:"Av. Benavides 344 - Miraflores", telefono:"01-4459700", estado:false},
            {nombre:"LINCE", direccion:"Jr. Tomás Guido 622 - Lince", telefono:"01-7481414", estado:false},
            {nombre:"LOS OLIVOS", direccion:"Av. Carlos Izaguirre 931", telefono:"01-7768893", estado:false},
            {nombre:"CALLAO", direccion:"Av. Saenz Peña 941 - Callao", telefono:"01 - 694 9645", estado:false},
            {nombre:"LA VICTORIA", direccion:" Prolongación Huánuco 2051", telefono:"01-7768893", estado:false},

            {nombre:"ABANCAY", direccion:"Jr. Huancavelica 413 - Apurímac", telefono:"083-323920", estado:false},
            {nombre:"CAJAMARCA", direccion:"Av. Evitamiento Norte 1807 - 1809", telefono:"076-261847", estado:false},
            {nombre:"CHIMBOTE", direccion:"Av. Pardo 1150 Santa", telefono:"043-281190", estado:false},
        ],
        mapaSedes:[
            {nombre:"SAN ISIDRO", mapa:"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3902.7528105136344!2d-77.07477358472353!3d-11.99159864414279!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x9105ce5be8ba21fb%3A0x292919764ae454a5!2sAv.+Carlos+Izaguirre+931%2C+Los+Olivos+15301!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2spe!4v1561161587300!5m2!1ses-419!2spe"},
            {nombre:"MIRAFLORES", mapa:"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3902.7528105136344!2d-77.07477358472353!3d-11.99159864414279!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x9105ce5be8ba21fb%3A0x292919764ae454a5!2sAv.+Carlos+Izaguirre+931%2C+Los+Olivos+15301!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2spe!4v1561161587300!5m2!1ses-419!2spe"},
            {nombre:"LINCE", mapa:"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3902.7528105136344!2d-77.07477358472353!3d-11.99159864414279!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x9105ce5be8ba21fb%3A0x292919764ae454a5!2sAv.+Carlos+Izaguirre+931%2C+Los+Olivos+15301!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2spe!4v1561161587300!5m2!1ses-419!2spe"},
            {nombre:"LOS OLIVOS", mapa:"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3902.7528105136344!2d-77.07477358472353!3d-11.99159864414279!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x9105ce5be8ba21fb%3A0x292919764ae454a5!2sAv.+Carlos+Izaguirre+931%2C+Los+Olivos+15301!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2spe!4v1561161587300!5m2!1ses-419!2spe"},
        ]
    },
    computed:{
        filteredList() {
            return this.sedesCorreos.filter(clasSede => {
              return clasSede.nombre.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
            })
        }
    },
    methods:{
        showModal (index){
        // console.log(index);
            this.sedesCorreos[index].estado=true;
            
       
        }
    }
})
```

```css
.vueSede {
  background: #f0f4f8;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 5em;
}
.vueSede .sedes-principal {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 12px;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 5em;
}
.vueSede .sedes-principal .sede-Vue {
  width: 350px;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 5px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #4572d3 0%, #2d4d90 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #9e9e9e;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.vueSede .sedes-principal .sede-Vue:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #4572d3 0, #4066b8 25%, #2d4d90);
  color: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.8s linear;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.vueSede .sedes-principal .sede-Vue p span {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.vueSede .sedes-principal .sede-Vue .btnVue {
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.vueSede .sedes-principal .sede-Vue .btnVue button {
  background: #ff7400;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  color: #fff;
}
.vueSede .sedes-principal .sede-Vue .btnVue button i {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.vueSede .sedes-principal .sede-VueUno {
  width: 350px;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 5px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #cc0d0d 0%, #0551f6 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #9e9e9e;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=search.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="vueSede" id="app">
        <div class="fond">
                <p class="buscador">
                 <label> <strong>BUSCAR: SEDE DE CORREOS DEL PERÚ</strong></label>
                 <input id="buscador" type="text"  placeholder="" v-model="search">  
               </p>
         </div>
         
      <div class="sedes-principal">
            <div  v-for="(sedefil, index) of  filteredList" >
                   <!--<p> {{index}}</p>--> 
                <div :class="[sedefil.estado ? 'sede-Vue':'sede-VueUno' ]"  >
                <p><span>Nombre:</span>  {{sedefil.nombre}}</p>
                <p><span>Direccion:</span>  {{sedefil.direccion}}</p>
                <p><span>Telefono:</span> {{sedefil.telefono}}</p>
                <p><span>estado:</span> {{sedefil.estado}}</p>
                <div class="btnVue">
                <button v-on:click="showModal(index)" class="btn btn-primary">ver mapa <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></button>  <!-- falta definir evento click-->   
                </div>
                </div>

                </div>

      </div>



</div>
```

a llamar.

Comment: Tu codigo esta medio confuso. Donde esta el modal? porque tu modal no es otro componente, que solo se muestre como modal? porque usas un estado en el array, que nunca volves a false, en lugar de copiar la fila y pasarsela al modal?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar

```
this.sedesCorreos[index].estado=!this.sedesCorreos[index].estado;
```

Que hará que se cambie de true a false según requieras